# Is there a solution for creating right-to-left tables using python-docx?

Tags: python, openxml, python-docx

I have been trying to create tables in right-to-left direction (meaning the first column is on the rightmost side of the table) using python-docx package in a word document. But I did not find any solutions so far.

Here is the snippet from the python-docx documentation ([here](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/enum/WdTableDirection.html)), but the table is still in left-to-right (default) direction.:

```
from docx.enum.table import WD_TABLE_DIRECTION

table = document.add_table(3, 3)
table.direction = WD_TABLE_DIRECTION.RTL
```

Also, I noticed that the <w:bidiVisuals/> tag with the document.xml in a docx package, is there while in a previously set manually RTL table using MS Word, but not in a LTR table. So I tried the following code, but still no results:

```
from docx.oxml.ns import nsdecls
from docx.oxml import parse_xml, OxmlElement
from docx import Document

def create_rtl_table(rows, cols):
    doc = Document()

 # Create a new table with 'rows' rows and 'cols' columns
    table = doc.add_table(rows=rows, cols=cols)

 # Set RTL direction for the table
    table._element.append(parse_xml(r'<w:tblPr %s><w:bidiVisual/></w:tblPr>' % nsdecls('w')))

 return doc


if __name__ == "__main__":
    rows = 3
    cols = 4
    document = create_rtl_table(rows, cols)
    document.save("rtl_table.docx")
```

The table still is left-to-right. I try to have a right-to-left directed table, can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

To create a right-to-left (RTL) directed table in a Word document using the python-docx package, you need to modify the tblPr (table properties) element of the table. The WD_TABLE_DIRECTION enumeration in python-docx only controls the layout direction of the text inside the cells, not the overall table direction.

You can achieve the RTL direction by setting the bidiVisual property of the table's properties. Here's how you can do it:

```
from docx import Document
from docx.oxml import OxmlElement
from docx.oxml.ns import nsdecls

def create_rtl_table(rows, cols):
    doc = Document()
    table = doc.add_table(rows=rows, cols=cols)

    
    tblPr = table._element.xpath('.//w:tblPr')[0]

    
    bidiVisual = OxmlElement('w:bidiVisual')
    tblPr.append(bidiVisual)

    return doc

if __name__ == "__main__":
    rows = 3
    cols = 4
    document = create_rtl_table(rows, cols)
    document.save("rtl_table.docx")
```

Comment: It worked, and my problem has been solved. Couldn't press +1 button.

Comment: What do u mean with +1 button?